# JavaScript/JQuery Issue with Slick Slider and YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, slick.js

Hi I am have an issue with Slick slider and YouTube video's that are auto-playing as you slide through. It was working but now when you navigate through the slider, its stops working and gets stuck. The video's will not play after this happens.

This is the code

```
var gridVideoList = new Array();
var gridPlayerList = new Array();
var timeout = false;

initialiseGridVideos();
resizeBackgroundVideos();

document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-collapse');
    for(var i = 0; i < navbar.length; i++) {
        if(navbar[i].classList.contains('in') && !evt.target.closest('.navbar')) {
            // Convert to jQuery object
            var $navbar = jQuery(navbar[i]);
            $navbar.collapse('hide');
        }
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    // clear the timeout
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  // start timing for event "completion"
  timeout = setTimeout(resizeBackgroundVideos, 250);
});

function resizeBackgroundVideos() {
    var backgroundVideos = document.getElementsByClassName('background-video');
    for(var i = 0; i < backgroundVideos.length; i++) {
        var video = backgroundVideos[i];
        var videoHeight = video.clientHeight;
        var videoIframe = video.getElementsByClassName('background-video__iframe')[0];
        var videoIframeWidth = (videoHeight / 56.25) * 100;
        var videoIframeHeight = videoHeight;
        videoIframe.style.width = videoIframeWidth + 'px';
        videoIframe.style.height = videoIframeHeight + 'px';
    }
}

function initialiseGridVideos() {
    var gridSlideshow = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-slideshow')[0];
    var grids = gridSlideshow ? gridSlideshow.getElementsByClassName('grid') : false;
    if(grids) {
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        for (var i = 0; i < grids.length; i++) {
            var video = grids[i].getElementsByClassName('grid-video')[0];
            if(video) {
                var playerID = video.getAttribute('id');
                var videoID = video.getAttribute('data-video-id');
                gridVideoList.push({ID: playerID, videoID: videoID});
            }
        }
    }
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    if(typeof gridVideoList === 'undefined') {
       return; 
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < gridVideoList.length; i++) {
        var autoplayVideo = i === 0 ? 1 : 0;
        var player = enableVideoAPI(gridVideoList[i], autoplayVideo);
        gridPlayerList.push(player);
    }
}

function enableVideoAPI(player, autoplayVideo) {
    return new YT.Player(player.ID, {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: player.videoID,
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: autoplayVideo,
            rel: 0,
            loop: 1,
            controls: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            showinfo: 0,
            disablekb: 1,
            modestbranding: 1,
            mute: 1,
            playlist: player.videoID
        },
        host: 'https://www.youtube.com'
    });
}

function playGridVideo(evt) {
    var gridColumn = evt.target.closest('.grid-column--one__video');
    var video = gridColumn.getElementsByClassName('grid-video')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < gridPlayerList.length; i++) {
        var playerID = gridPlayerList[i].a.id;
        if(playerID === video.getAttribute('id')) {
            gridPlayerList[i].playVideo();
            break;
        }
    }
}

function stopGridVideoOnSlideSchange() {
    for (var i = 0; i < gridPlayerList.length; i++) {
            gridPlayerList[i].stopVideo();
    }
}


function startNewGridVideoOnSlideChange() {

    var gridSlideshow = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-slideshow')[0];
    var currentSlide = gridSlideshow.getElementsByClassName('slick-active')[0];
    var currentVideo = currentSlide.getElementsByClassName('grid-video')[0];

    if(currentVideo) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gridPlayerList.length; i++) {
        var playerID = gridPlayerList[i].a.id;
            if(playerID === currentVideo.getAttribute('id')) {
                gridPlayerList[i].playVideo();
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

}
(function($) {

    $('.grid-slideshow').slick({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        dots: true,
        dotsClass: 'grid-slideshow__dots',
        prevArrow: '<button class="button--circle button--white slick-arrow slick-prev grid-slideshow__prev"><span class="sr-only">Previous</span><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button class="button--circle button--white slick-arrow slick-next grid-slideshow__next"><span class="sr-only">Next</span><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>'
    });

    $('.testimonials-slideshow__slide-container').slick({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        prevArrow: '<button class="button--circle slick-arrow slick-prev testimonials-slideshow__prev"><span class="sr-only">Previous</span><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button class="button--circle slick-arrow slick-next testimonials-slideshow__next"><span class="sr-only">Next</span><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>'
    });

    $('.logo-slideshow__list').slick({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: true,
        responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
              }
            }
          ]
    });

    $('.grid-slideshow').on('afterChange', function(slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        stopGridVideoOnSlideSchange();
        startNewGridVideoOnSlideChange();
    });

})( jQuery );
```

The errors seems to be coming from this line of code.

`var playerID = gridPlayerList[i].a.id;`